# Silverlight woes/questions

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

1) How can I use strongly typed dictionaries? I have some in my codebehind for an xaml page, but it does not come in intellisense and I have added System.Collections to the namespaces.

2) I hear "CoreCLR" a lot when talking about Silverlight. Is this a stripped down version of the CLR? Is there any classes/namespaces I can't use in Silverlight 3.0?

3) If I set an animation in C# code behind, do I need to do anything in the xaml? I ask because I saw one example of an animation set in C# but the XAML was likewise modified.

4) How can I make an object grow in size (Scale transform) over a certain set period of time via C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need to add System.Collections.Generic

2) Yes it is stripped down, [this is a list of what is supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838194(VS.95).aspx)

3) In Silverlight 3 you don't need to do anything in the code behind if you use System.Windows.Interactivity and the ControlStoryboardAction behavior in Microsoft.Expression.Interactions. Otherwise just call the begin method in your code behind. Either is valid.

4) Change the Height and Width with a storyboard, set the duration on the storyboard. There's plenty of examples on Microsoft's site and 4 questions in one means you get no code ;)

Comment: Thanks! Answer to 3) sounds quite straightforward, just setting properties really. Thanks for this.

Comment: Yeah, it's simple to do in Blend 3.